# Eliminate the side effects of padding-left

Tags: css

I have the following code:

**CSS**

```
#page {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
#page #bar {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="bar">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
</div>
```

What should I put in CSS `#page #bar` to eliminate the extra part outside the red box ?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `width: 100%;`

block elements (*like `div`*) will fill their containers' width by default (*taking care of paddings*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/1/

---

It is no a side-effect. It is how it **should** based on the current box-model.

If you ***have*** to (*not in your case*) specify a width then you can alter the `box-sizing` property of that rule to

```
#page #bar {
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #00F;

    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/4/

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) attribute:

```
#page #bar {    
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #00F;

   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
   box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

What this means is that `100% width` applies to the whole element, including the borders - so the nested element will be resized so that its borders are within the parent.

The default is `content-box` which means that `100% width` is applied to the content - the content area is made the same width as the parent.

Comment: @c-link it works.. but you need to add vendor prefixes as well.. `-moz-`, `-webkit-` etc..

Comment: @C-Link - yes, I did test it. I did add browser-specific attributes to the answer as well, as not all browsers support it otherwise.

Comment: oh! yeah but even in new browser i'm using firefox 22 . after declaring vendor prefix then it worked....

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly know what you are looking to accomplish by setting *padding-left* to the #bar element, but you can remove the unwanted padding on left by using the *:last-child* CSS pseudo class as shown below:

```
#page #bar:last-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle implementing the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/9/

PS: at least `box-sizing` is not gonna fix this issue

Comment: *sidenote:* `:last-child` is only available after IE9

Comment: Okay, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/15/) explains how it can be done on IE7+ using the `:first-child` pseudo class.

Comment: That fiddle was not updated. Have updated the link, check it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class

```
#page #bar {
    width: 98%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Ege2Y/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease the width to `something like 97%`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ege2Y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change your width into 97% in #page #bar

Answer (score 0):

```
#page #bar {
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the best answer is picked, I would like to share another approach.

Just add `overflow: hidden` in `#page` and the "side effect" will be resolved as well.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xynLH/) demo.